# PySpark - Sum a column in dataframe and return results as int

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column of numbers. I need to sum that column and then have the result return as an int in a python variable.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 20), ("B", 30), ("D", 80)],["Letter", "Number"])
```

I do the following to sum the column.

```
df.groupBy().sum()
```

But I get a dataframe back.

```
+-----------+
|sum(Number)|
+-----------+
|        130|
+-----------+
```

I would 130 returned as an int stored in a variable to be used else where in the program.

```
result = 130
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The simplest way really :

```
df.groupBy().sum().collect()
```

But it is very slow operation: [Avoid groupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html), you should use RDD and reduceByKey:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: (1,x[1])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).collect()[0][1]
```

I tried on a bigger dataset and i measured the processing time:

RDD and ReduceByKey : **2.23 s**

GroupByKey: 30.5 s

Comment: Great! It worked!
But what if I need to sum all columns?
I tried to do: df.groupBy().sum().collect()[0].asDict() but my data doesnt fit in memory, so I`m trying to use your tip as workaround.

For exemplo: 

list(map(lambda x: df.select(list(x)).groupBy().sum().collect()[0].asDict(), np.array_split(PossibleNulls, 10)))

worked! 

But, too slow ;(

Answer (score 54):

I think the simplest way:

```
df.groupBy().sum().collect()
```

will return a list.
In your example:

```
In [9]: df.groupBy().sum().collect()[0][0]
Out[9]: 130
```

Comment: How does it Understand which column to groupBy and which one to Sum ?

Answer (score 44):

If you want a specific column :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F     

df.agg(F.sum("my_column")).collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: The function would return a dataframe, I just need the int value.

Comment: Oh yeah didn't see the detail, sorry. I've modified

Comment: Returns a list now

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 17):

This is another way you can do this. using `agg` and `collect`:

```
sum_number = df.agg({"Number":"sum"}).collect()[0]

result = sum_number["sum(Number)"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers, but without the use of a groupby or agg.  I just select the column in question, sum it, collect it, and then grab the first two indices to return an int.  The only reason I chose this over the accepted answer is I am new to pyspark and was confused that the 'Number' column was not explicitly summed in the accepted answer.  If I had to come back after sometime and try to understand what was happening, syntax such as below would be easier for me to follow.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f   

df.select(f.sum('Number')).collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: Answers to this question are confusingly similar to each other. Can you add a note explaining how this improves on other answers here?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `first()` function. It returns the first row from the dataframe, and you can access values of respective columns using indices.

```
df.groupBy().sum().first()[0]
```

In your case, the result is a dataframe with single row and column, so above snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

Select column as RDD, abuse `keys()` to get value in Row (or use `.map(lambda x: x[0])`), then use RDD sum:

```
df.select("Number").rdd.keys().sum()
```

SQL sum using [`selectExpr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html):

```
df.selectExpr("sum(Number)").first()[0]
```

Answer (score -2):

The following should work:

```
df.groupBy().sum().rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
```

Answer (score -3):

sometimes read a csv file to pyspark Dataframe, maybe the numeric column change to string type '23',like this, you should use pyspark.sql.functions.sum to get the result as int , not sum()

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F                                                    
df.groupBy().agg(F.sum('Number')).show()
```