# Divding column of Dataframe by constant value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Data frame in below format.

```
| Occupation | wa_rating | Genre |
| engineer | 935 | Musical |
```

Now I want to divide Rating column of this Dataframe by totalRatings.

but when I am doing

```
resultDF = joinedDF.select(col("wa_rating")/totalRating)
```

It is giving me below error.

```
unsupported literal type class java.util.Arraylist
```

Comment: Looks like "totalRating" type is Arraylist; division on such type is not allowed even in regular Scala.

Comment: @pasha701 totalRating is an constant number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely your `totalRating` variable is a list. For example `[100]`. And you can't divide a number by a list. This throws your error:

```
resultDF = joinedDF.select(col("wa_rating")/[100])
```

but this does not

```
resultDF = joinedDF.select(col("wa_rating")/100)
```

Check that `totalRating` is an actual number (a float or integer). If it's a list containing a number, simply extract the number from it.

EDIT:

From your comments, we now know that your `totalRating` is a list. You can transform it to a number with:

```
totalRating = joinedDF3.groupBy().sum("Rating").collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: I have created totalRating as follow
 totalRating = joinedDF3.groupBy().sum("Rating").collect().  Is there a way to create a list instead of this number.

Comment: Ayush, If you want your command to work, `totalRating` needs to be a number, not a list. Your expression `totalRating = joinedDF3.groupBy().sum("Rating").collect()` returns a list as I suspected in my answer. You don't want that. You want to extract the number inside the list `totalRating` as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812526/pyspark-sum-a-column-in-dataframe-and-return-results-as-int?rq=1)

Comment: Your `totalRating` needs to be `totalRating = joinedDF3.groupBy().sum("Rating").collect()[0][0]`

Comment: Cool, please accept my answer if you are happy with it