# Dataframe Row(sum(fld)) to a discrete value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have this:

```
df = sqlContext.sql(qry)
df2 = df.withColumn("ext", df.lvl * df.cnt)
ttl = df2.agg(F.sum("ext")).collect()
```

which returns this:

`[Row(sum(ext)=1285430)]`

How do devolve this down to just the discreet value `1285430` without it being a list Row(sum())?

I've researched and tried so many things I'm totally stymed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark - Sum a column in dataframe and return results as int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812526/pyspark-sum-a-column-in-dataframe-and-return-results-as-int)

Comment: Also, you flagged this as databricks, but I don't think there's anything here that's specific to databricks and there is a lot more information available if you search for spark or pyspark instead of specifying databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for collect:

```
n = ...your transformation logic and agg... .first().getInt(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the first row and then get the first element as int.

`df2.agg(F.sum("ext")).collect()(0).getInt(0)`

Take a look at the documentation: [Spark ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row).

Answer (score 0):

Also can df.collect()[0][0]  -or-  df.collect()[0]['sum(ext)']